# Continue with older commit in Git

Tags: git, version-control

I have a git problem i encounter quite often.

Lets say i have a git repository and i have already made a few commits:

```
[C1] --> [C2] --> [C3]
```

Now i start a new thing/feature - and i'm working a while on it - creating more commits

```
[C1] --> [C2] --> [C3] --> [C4] --> [C5]
```

After some time I start to realize that everything I have done in this direction is wrong ( all commits starting from [C4] ).

Now i would like to continue my project from Commit 3 - resulting in something like this:

```
                         +-------------------+
                        /                     \
[C1] --> [C2] --> [C3] +-> [C4] --> [C5]       +--> [C6] --> [C7] --> ...
```

I don' want to loose [C4] and [C5] in the progress, after all its a version control system and perhaps something i wrote will come in handy later. *(And also just deleting it would even more feel like wasted time)*

I'm not sure if this is do-able and if it is, if this would be considered a good practice.
So i would also be open on tips how to do it better or different.

If possible i would like to prevent creating new branches - i am the only commiter to my projects and the history is most of the time quite linear, so i think complex branching would be a little bit of overkill (but as i said - i have only little knowledge about git).

Comment: Just use a branch - it's quite simple and it maps exactly to the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: why dont you use a branch? Merge the branch only when you are pretty sure about your changes

Comment: But if i understand correctly i would start a branch before making C4 and C5. But what if i already have commited these and then later  realised I dont want these ?

Comment: Even if you do `git reset --hard C3` you won't loose C4 and C5 as you will be always able to recover them with `git reflog`. But you also might want to create a branch on top of C5 and name it e.g. `resetted-work` if that's easier for you to use later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have issues with using GUI Apps, try [**SourceTree**](https://www.atlassian.com/software/sourcetree/overview) from *Atlassian*.

It gives option to reverse the code changes. All your commits will be intact even if you reverse them.

Comment: Currently I'm using SmartGit - is this a feature exclusive to SourceTree or can i perhaps do the same in smartGit ?

Comment: This might help [SmartGit-Revert](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgithg/documentation/5/show?page=commands-branch#revert)

Comment: Yes, i think thats what i searched for. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

How about using git rebase? This should do what you want it to do.

http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase

Answer (score 1):

Just make a branch when you realise you need to go back to a previous point

```
git branch saved-C5
```

then

```
git reset --hard C3
```

(possibly followed by a git clean -f -d to remove new files and directories added by C4 and C5)

Your master is now at C3 and you can continue working there.